# Microsoft Access - Create Form to Post Data to Intersection Table

Tags: ms-access, relational-database, ms-access-2013

I am sincerely sorry if this question has been asked before, however with my limited knowledge of using Microsoft Access forms I am having an issue that is likely a very simple fix.

At the moment I am trying to create a form that will allow me to post data into an intersection table using combo boxes, the purpose is to create a relation between Clients and Project Numbers, these are intended on being a Many-to-Many relationship.

[Relation Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLQ87.png)

To begin with one issue I am running into is that when I use the intersection table to select a unique Client Name I get multiple entries from the drop down menu when there are multiple items in the intersecting table.

[Form Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2dIt.png)

The second part of my issue is that I am unsure how to post data to the intersecting table once the dropdown selections have been made.

Any help is greatly appreciated, and I thank everyone for their time.

Answer (score 1):

The first part is to create a form in which you find, and edit data in the main client table.

This form will ONLY be based on the single main client table.

You perhaps ALREADY have a nice form to edit the client table anyway. I mean, how else will users find and edit a client anyway? So this issue and problem will LONG be dealt with before you do anything else of use in the application.

The form based on this single table might look like this:

[image]

Ok, now close the above, and create a second form to allow adding some choices of favorite colors (or in your case ClientContract). So the form will be based on this child table.

Again, like the first form, this form is based on ONE table.

Make this form continues, so click on ClientContract table, and then from ribbon choose multiple items form from the ribbon. It will look like this:

[image]

Of course we don’t want the user to have to manually type in the color (or project in your case), so we drop in a combo box from the ribbon and use the wizard. MAKE sure the first column of this combo is the PK of the ProjectNumber table, but FOR EASE of reading and selection, include ProjectNumber and Project Description columns in that comb box. NOTE in above how I also had added that combo box.

Assuming you closed and saved this form.

Now open our first main client form in design mode, and drag + drop in the continues second form we just created onto this form. The resulting form will look like this:

[image]
Access will automatic set up he customer_ID for us (because it is a sub form attached to the main form that only displays the one main record).

Once the above works, then again close the lot, and open up our continues form in design mode and remove all the extra junk.
(leaving ONLY the combo box).

The result is this:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it is much appreciated, this definitely worked for me!